# Java: efficiently (and safely) remove sequence of elements in a final SortedMap<K,V>?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I'm trying to trace a memory leak in Java. Does this snippet actually prevent the garbage collection.

```
SortedMap<K,V> cache = ... /* some sorted map */

// and later in a loop, I do

cache = cache.tailMap(someIndex); // does this prevent gc of elements < someIndex
```

The elements < someIndex are not available anymore in follow-up code. Are they also garbage collected? I'm running into a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` after a while, not sure if this is the reason...

I cannot create a temporary map and reassign like

```
tmp = new SortedMap<K,V>();
tmp.putAll(cache.tailMap(someIndex));
cache.clear();
cache = tmp; // this breaks the "final"
```

as I need the original `cache` object, because it's final. How do I schedule those elements < someIndex for GC, i.e. do I really need to call `remove()` in a loop? Is there a better way than this?

```
// "TreeSet" to make sure the keys are ordered
Iterator<K> it = new TreeSet<K>(cache.keySet()).iterator();
while (it.hasNext())
{
    if (it.next() < someIndex) it.remove();
    else break;
}
```

**Edit: SOLVED**

Actually the above was not working as expected. Of couse, it was necessary to remove the elements in the map, not within the keyset!

```
// "TreeSet" to make sure the keys are ordered
Iterator<K> it = new TreeSet<K>(cache.keySet()).iterator();
while (it.hasNext())
{
   K key = it.next();
    if (key < someIndex) cache.remove(key); // not it.remove();
    else break;
}
```

**Edit 2**

Most elegant, as suggested by Louis Wassermann below, this is what I was originally after:

```
cache.headMap(someIndex).clear();
```

No iterator, no key set, no need to loop - beautiful! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javadoc (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#tailMap(K)) is quite clear : the `tailMap()` method return a view of the map, backed by the original map. Elements are not removed from the original map, and the original map is still reachable as the new map has a reference on it.

In your case, you must call remove to effectively make objets garbageable.

Comment: That is very unfortunate, but I kind of expected that answer :-( Do you know a way to "batch-remove" elements?

Comment: `clear()` method ? I think you should look at a more evolued solution, Guava Cache is a good option.

Comment: Or maybe try to look at `entrySet().removeAll()` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)) or `entrySet().retainAll()` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection))

Comment: @Muelleth if you want to remove all the elements before `index`, just do `map.headMap(index).clear()`.  One line, very simple.

Answer (score 1):

If `cache` is reachable from a GC root, then the map and its keys will not be eligible for garbage collection. What you looking for is a key eviction policy or data-structure.

[Guava Cache](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html) might be a good option.

Comment: Thank you! Guava Cache looks very promising, I will certainly look into that. Unfortunately I cannot introduce an external dependency at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `tailMap()` creates a view that retains a reference to the parent object. You need to clean up that parent object.

```
SortedMap<K,V> cache = ... /* some sorted map */
// and later in a loop, DO THIS INSTEAD: 
cache.headMap(someIndex, false).clear();
```

This change through the `headMap()` view removes unnecessary entries from the underlying `cache` map.